# Make field Description mandatory for a project of type Escalation and issue type CustomerEscalation

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I would like to make the description field required for the Escalation project and the issue type Customer escalation. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that through creating a different Field Configuration for that project.

So it works like this -

You have a Field Configuration Scheme.

Then inside the Scheme you can have multiple Field Configurations - each attached to different issue types. In other words, you can make some fields mandatory for Tasks but not for Stories.

Then you attach the Scheme to the project.

So if you want Field Q to be mandatory on project ABC, then you would create a Field Configuration Scheme for project ABC. I like to abbreviate so something like Project ABC FCS (where FCS is Field Configuration Scheme). It would include an FC (field configuration) that has field Q as mandatory.

Then I would attach Project ABC FCS to project ABC.

I would leave the existing scheme on the other projects where it is not mandatory.